# Largest Sum of Averages

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

[Problem Statement](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-sum-of-averages/):

> We partition a row of numbers A into at most K adjacent (non-empty)
>   groups, then our score is the sum of the average of each group. What
>   is the largest score we can achieve?
>
> Note that our partition must use every number in A, and that scores
>   are not necessarily integers.

I am specifically trying to understand the approach behind the set generation . Consider following example array.

> N= 5, Elements: [9,1,2,3,9,8]
>
> k = 3

The questions asks to generate steps up-to size k. For instance, we can have following generated sets (though the actual set would be larger).

> - [9,1,2] & [3,9,8]
> - [9], [1,2,3], [9, 8]
> - [9,1,2], [3], [9, 8]

I am trying to understand the naive recursive solution with no memoization.

**Question:**

> I added logs to understand how these sets are generated. I am unable
>   to understand how the sets [9,1,2] [3,9,8] will be generated using the
>   following code snippet. More importantly how does it cover all
>   possible setups upto size 3.

```
  public double largestSumOfAverages(int[] arr, int groupSize) {
    int[] sum = new int[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum[i] = arr[i] + (i > 0 ? sum[i - 1] : 0);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
    return dfs(arr, groupSize, sum, arr.length, 0);
  }

  public double dfs(int[] arr, int groupSize, int[] sumToIthIndex, int right, int left) {
    if (groupSize == 1) {
      double avg1 = ((double) (sumToIthIndex[right - 1] - sumToIthIndex[left] + arr[left]) / (right
          - left));

      System.out.println(" dfs return :: " + left + " right:: " + right + "  :grpSize:: " + groupSize);
      return avg1;
    }
    double num = 0;
    for (int index = left; index + groupSize <= right; index++) {
      System.out.println(" dfs left:: " + index + " right:: " + right + "  :grpSize:: " + groupSize);
      num = Math.max(num,
          ((double) (sumToIthIndex[index] - sumToIthIndex[left] + arr[left]) / (index - left
              + 1)) + dfs(arr, groupSize - 1, sumToIthIndex, right,index + 1));
    }
    System.out.println("End");
    return num;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need to cover all possible setups up to size 3 because you will `ALWAYS` want to use the maximum number of groups available to you (assuming all values are positive).

Suppose that the group size is `k` and you found an optimal answer with `k-1` groups. If you take one of these groups, take the highest value from it and put it into its own group then you'd have a higher or equal score, therefore your answer was not really optimal. (The average of n numbers is never higher than the largest of those numbers)

Comment: Can you explain that with an example?

Comment: My apologies for posting this question, Now after going through your answer, I now realize, I interpreted the question incorrectly. I thought we can select as many groups as possible, with the condition that any group will have at max "K" members. For example [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] & K = 3. The following group is valid [1], [2,3,4], [5,6], [7], as all member groups has at most 3 values. Though this group is invalid [1,2,3,4][5],[6],[7] as one of the groups has 4 members. I wonder, what would be the solution to such a  question, simply finding the largest value in the array, will that work?

Comment: Well, the solution to your interpretation would be to have each element into its own group since A + B > (A+B)/2

Comment: Thanks, that's what my intuition was,  but the equation makes things concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the algorithm but what I would do is trying to do the example with my head, to understand how the code works.
Here I made the first iteration of the loop :

```
FIRST ITERATION
1) groupeSize = 3, right = 6, left = 0, index = 0, 
    num = max(0, ((9 - 9 + 9) / 1) + <5.5>)) = 14.5
2) groupeSize = 2, right = 6, left = 1, index = 0,
    num1 = max(0, ((9 - 10 + 1 / (0 - 1 + 1)) + <5.5>)) = 5.5
3) groupeSize = 1, right = 6, left = 2, index = 0, avg1 = ((32 - 12 + 2) / (6-2)) = 5.5
```

Which corresponds to the sum of the average of `[9,1,2], [3], [9, 8]`

Each 1), 2),... is a recursion and all the values between `<>` is know in the reverse order (when going back up from the recursion)

Try to continue to understand ! Good luck !